# how to calculate average rating

Tags: c#, logic

Sorry if I am not clear:

How would I calculate the average rating based on the MinRate and MaxRate

for example: **minRate** = 0 or 1 and **MaxRate** = 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 0

How would I calculate the rating?

**Update End**

I am implementing a 5 star rating system and my table structure has two columns:
1) MinRate 2) MaxRate

so my question is: how do calculate the average rating?

here is how I have in my 5 star rating implementation.

```
int[] {7, 0, 0, 8, 5};
```

This means that:

- 7 users rated the article with a 1
- 0 users rated the article with a 2
- 0 users rated the article with a 3
- 8 users rated the article with a 4
- 5 users rated the article with a 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code:

```
double avg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) // arr.Length should be the same as MaxRate
{
    avg += arr[i] * (i + MinRate);
}
avg /= arr.length;
```

Comment: its an array that holds the values as you showed in the question

Comment: this example (int[] {7, 0, 0, 8, 5}) i have showed in my question is just to get an idea... this array dynamically populated from db.

Comment: then just replace arr with the name of your dynamically populated array

Comment: what if; if i have only two diminsion array int[] {1,5} ?

Comment: @Abu, you mean 2 values. In that case you would replace MaxRate with the length of the array.

Comment: there is no MaxRate you mean minRate ?

Comment: MaxRate should be equal to the length of the array, in that case it's equal to 2

Comment: @Abu, you're defining it.... as you show in your example im guessing you populate the array from the database and also retrieve the min and max rate for that particular rating...

Comment: This code is plain wrong. You need to devide by the total number of voters, not the length of the array. See dpp's answer

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] x =  {7, 0, 0, 8, 5}; 
/* 
    7 x 1 star
    0 x 2 stars
    0 x 3 stars
    8 x 4 stars
    5 x 5 stars
*/

float totalVoters = 0;
float totalPoints = 0;

for(i = 1; i <= x.length; i++)
{
    //add 7, 0, 0, 8, 5
    totalVoters += x[i];

    /* add
        7 x 1 star = 7,
        0 x 2 stars = 0,
        0 x 3 stars = 0,
        8 x 4 stars = 32,
        5 x 5 stars = 25
    */
    totalPoints += x[i] * i;
}

response.write(totalPoints/totalVoters); //get the average
```

Comment: I thing you should replace `totalPoints += totalVoters` with `totalPoints += x[i]`, as your're weighting the *total* by the number of points each time, not the individual set of voters.

Comment: Justin: i am not sure how will that work, it will fill `int[] {7, 0, 0, 8, 5}; ` this dynamically and values will change since its coming from the db, and i just gave the example to get an idea. i hope i am clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know ASP.NET, but the average is just the total divided by the number of items:

```
(int[0] + int[1] * 2 + int[2] * 3 + int[3] * 4 + int[4] * 5) / 5
```

So in a loop (won't work, as `int` is reserved, but you get the idea):

```
float average = 0;

for (int i = minrate; i < maxrate; i++) {
  average += int[i] * i;
}

average /= maxrate;
```

Comment: that wont' work because each one has a different weight it should be int[0] + int[1] * 2 + int[2] * 3.... etc

Comment: @Jesus: Whoops, sorry. Didn't notice that the array didn't hold the *total* scores.

Comment: that's ok, easy to miss stuff sometimes :P

Comment: What exactly do `minrate` and `maxrate` do? Are you saying that they define the interval in which you can rate (like from `2` to `4` instead of `1` to `5`?). I updated my code to work with that.

Comment: if minRate =1 means its one star, and if maxRate is = 2 means two start, or 3 mean three star.....5 means five star...

Comment: So if I have `minRate = 3` and `maxRate = 5`, I can only vote for 3, 4, or 5?

Comment: no no... its a rating system.... its like likes/dislikes; likes (maxRate) and dislikes (minRate)... minRate can only be 0 or 1 and maxRate can be 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 0 as i said in my question.

Comment: I'm confused. What do the two values do? How do they even relate to the average rating?

Comment: i agree with you but i have no choice but to follow the structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
((7*1)+(8*4)+(5*5))/(7+8+5) = 3.2
```

Comment: include 0, they are part of the formula I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did

```
   private static double GetRating()
        {
            int star5 = 12801;
            int star4 = 4982;
            int star3 = 1251;
            int star2 = 429;
            int star1 = 1265;

            double rating = (double)(5 * star5 + 4 * star4 + 3 * star3 + 2 * star2 + 1 * star1) / (star1 + star2 + star3 + star4 + star5);

            rating = Math.Round(rating, 1);

            return rating;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double rating = GetRating();
            Console.WriteLine("Your product rating: " + rating);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to use in the 5 of 5 votes:

```
// 36 = excellent (5), 49 = good (4), 17 = average (3), 5 = bad (2), 9 = terrible (1)
var values = new[] {36, 49, 17, 5, 9};

var result = GetRating(values).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
MessageBox.Show(result); // 3.84

public static double GetRating(int[] ratings)
{
    double ratingsSum = 0;
    double ratingsTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        ratingsSum += ratings[i - 1];
        ratingsTotal += i * ratings[5 - i];
    }
    var average = ratingsTotal / ratingsSum;
    return Math.Round(average, 2);
}
```